# Will MWKProgressIndicator cause app rejection?

Tags: ios, app-store

I will use the [MWKProgressIndicator](https://github.com/mwkoelb/MWKProgressIndicator) as a progress indicator in my project. Will this cause my app to be rejected on the basis of the human interface guideline?

I don't think it should, but I wanted to be sure before starting to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why it would.  Is there a specific part os the guidelines that you think it'll interfere with?

Comment: I read all but there are some examples.There are popular controls in github but they can get rejected.For example: [like this one](https://github.com/jaydee3/JDStatusBarNotification/issues/30) or another example is:  [this](https://github.com/cruffenach/CRToast/issues/140).I wanted to make sure before starting to include it into my project.

Comment: Looks like those controls are blocking the status bar, which you are not doing.

Also, in their rejection notice, it says, "Specifically, we noticed that your app provides an overlay that partially or totally blocks the status bar."

Comment: Yes, but the other 2,500  people didn't suffer from any rejection in example links.They liked the repo and starred it.But there are some people surprisingliy got rejected their apps.And I'm afraid of a surprise rejection because of the way I use this progress indicator in my project.So I want to be %100 sure before starting to use it.